# Public folder on Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess, frameworks

I  installed the Zend Framework, but I have a big problem here. When I entered on the public folder of my application (localhost/webserver/project/public/), I had that error:

> An error occurred
>
> Page not found
>
> Exception information:
>
> ## Message: Invalid controller specified (public)
>
> Stack trace:
>
> 0 C:\webserver\project\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954):
>   Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), 
>   Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
>
> 1 C:\webserver\project\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): >end_Controller_Front->dispatch()
>
> 2 C:\webserver\project\library\Zend\Application.php(366): >Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
>
> 3 C:\webserver\project\public\index.php(40): Zend_Application->run()
>
> 4 {main}
>
> ## Request Parameters:
>
> array (
>
> 'controller' => 'public',
>
> 'action' => 'index',
>
> 'module' => 'default',
>
> )

My public folder is interpreted like a controller. 
I'm running the application in Apache2.2 and PHP5.3  with the Xampp.

My Document_Root set on the htdoc is "C:/webserver", because I use other application on the same server. I'm using the Rewrite Rules in my htaccess on the public folder.

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

How can I make that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your application.ini and add

```
resources.frontController.baseurl = "webserver/project/public"
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, that's it! But the path what worked was `resources.frontController.baseurl = "/project/public"`

Comment: glad it helped and don't forget to check the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try creating virtual hosts for your projects. A better explanation is in: [ZEND FRAMEWORK](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html) and [virtual host in apache](http://zendguru.wordpress.com/2009/04/24/apache-setting-virtual-host-on-local-system/). Sorry about the english

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but if I have a server that I can't modify the htdoc file ? That's the problem.